# WordPress Import Error Demo Contents

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, multisite

I have a multi-purpose theme, which allow to download complete demo site content/wordpress.
Normally (www.example.com) it's perfect and run all demo request, last time i install a new **wordpress network** and enabled as **Network theme**.
[image: I am using this for importing demo]

In next multisite, whenever i try to fetch content through demo import option in sub-multi-site(example.com/sub), i receive following error

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in
/home/user/public_html/user/myyweb.folder/wp-content/themes/xyz/functions/importer/import.php on line 103
```

Line number 103 in import.php

```
$data       = unserialize( base64_decode( $file_data['body']));
```

Comment: Anyone? answer this?

Comment: still no answer???